# How can i check if the Android Device That Runs My App Run On version 4.2.2 and lower

Tags: java, android, gps

im creating a GPS app , im trying to check if the devce that runs the app runs on version 4.2.2 or lower .
if so the app can turn on / off the GPS service by it self with the command

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

now if the device runs a version higher then 4.2.2 , the user will get a pupout message that link him for the manual turn on of GPS.
thanks.

Comment: you mean Android Version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
    // Do something for JellyBean and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before JellyBean
}
```

The following though would give you a  more exact number like 4.2.2 whereas the above one will make a rough check on the API level.

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html